# JQuery How to hide a specific radio button item in Radio Button List

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I have one button and one radio button list server controls with four values(example: India,China,Us,Australia), when i click on the button, radio button list item with value "china" should be disabled. we are working on asp.net c#

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
   $("input[type=radio][value=china]").attr("enabled", false);
});
```